# cscript calling powershell - not writing file using '>' or out-file cmdlet

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wsh

Scenario:

Wanted to wrap some powershell in vbscript because we need to pull CPU info from a bunch of servers simultaneously and drop the result into individual files. I've done similar before using vbscript to 'fork' a Powershell command and return immediately, effectively a number of servers can be explored simultaneously without having to wait for each to return sequentially.

Platform happens to be XP (no choice).

In the PowerShell Prompt:

```
Get-counter 
-computername thehost1 -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 5 
-Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" > out1.text
```

Is find.... get the file written out.

From VBS:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "powershell -nologo -command Get-counter 
-computername thehost1 -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 5 
-Counter ""\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"" | Out-File ""out1.txt"" ",0
```

It runs but no output file is created or errors printed when the powershell is executed from VBS (tried also with the '>' instead of the Out-file servlet).

Trying to debug (showing the a truncated list of possible args that can be used with cscript):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\XX>cscript
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.7
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: CScript scriptname.extension [option...] [arguments...]

Options:
    //D         Enable Active Debugging
    //I         Interactive mode (default, opposite of //B)
    //X         Execute script in debugger
```

Produced no debugger or any other output.

Any clue as to what could be going wrong here?

Many thanks

Kevin

Comment: I suspect that the file is being created in a different folder. Probably the default working dir for powershell which I believe is C:\Sindows\System32. Check there. Also try using an explicit path for the file.

Comment: Did try using a specific file path, will have a check on the machine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the quotes around `"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"` are causing the problem.

You're not seeing any errors because the VBScript is successfully running PowerShell and does not know that the PowerShell script line is failing.

I got it to work by changing the `"` to `'`, like this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "powershell -nologo -command Get-counter -computername thehost1 -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 5 -Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time' >C:\YourPath\out1.txt", 0
```